# Spring Boot native image plugin: mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image How to config name and version?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

My file `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Focus at

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Spring Boot native image plugin:

```bash
mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image
```

[image]

How to config name and version for docker image?

I want change default name and version, how to archive?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is in the [documentation for the `spring-boot:build-image` goal of the Spring Boot Maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization). This documentation includes [an example of configuring the image name and tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.custom-image-name).

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <name>example.com/library/${project.artifactId}</name>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please help me set arguments, variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77048749/spring-boot-native-image-plugin-mvn-pnative-spring-bootbuild-image-how-to-pas