# Spring Boot native image plugin: mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image How to pass argument and environment variables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

Spring Boot native image plugin: `mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image` How to pass argument and environment variables?

If I use Dockerfile, I can config arg and environment variables like

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6

ARG SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
ENV SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL $SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
EXPOSE ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}

ARG SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
ENV SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME $SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
EXPOSE ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}

ARG SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
ENV SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD $SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
EXPOSE ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

ARG SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO
ENV SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO $SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO
EXPOSE ${SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO}

COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENV TZ=Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Spring Boot native image plugin, I didn't see Dockerfile, how to set ARG, env variables?

Comment: you already got the right answer when you asked https://stackoverflow.com/a/77048691/24069 -  please take a look at the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to what you are doing in the `Dockerfile` when using `spring-boot:build-image` with Paketo buildpacks would be to set runtime environment variables  for the Paketo Environment Variables buildpack as [documented by the Paketo project](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#runtime-environment-variables):

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <image>
                    <env> 
                        <BPE_SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL>
                            ${env.SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
                        </BPE_SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL>
                    </env>
                </image>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, putting sensitive values like usernames and passwords in an image like this is not a good idea, as anyone who can download the image can see the values of the environment variables. You should consider setting the values when the image is run instead of when it is built.

One way to do this is to use bindings as [described in the Paketo documentation](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#bindings). Some bindings are consumed automatically by the [Spring Cloud Bindings](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bindings) library that the Paketo buildpacks will automatically add to an image. The [Spring Boot `configtree` feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.configtree) can also be used to read bindings files in an image at runtime.